# Does \\ in the last line of an array have any effect?

Tags: tables, equations, line-breaking, arrays

Consider the following example:

```
\begin{array}{l}
line 1 \\
line 2 \\
\end{array}
```

Is the `\\` in the last line completely optional or are there circumstances under which it has any effect?

Comment: If you want to add a horizonal line at the bottom. You need the `\\ ` there. If you don't want anything underneath then the `\\ ` is superfluous and has no effect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @whlt3 said it is required if you intend to have a final horizontal line `\hline` or a partical line via `\cline{...}` or if you want to have some extra space blow that line produced via the optional argument of `\\`. If not then it is completely optional. I would however suggest to use `\\` on all lines as that allows you to easily add or reorder rows in your table without the need to worry about the row markers.

However, as @egreg pointed out this is only true for `tabular` or `array` environments: within `amsmath` environments such as `align` the `\\`functions as a row separator so that a final `\\`will result in a spurious extra row.

Comment: While a final ``\\`` is optional in `array` or `tabular` environments, it *mustn't*  be used in environments such as `align` or `gather`, where it produces a spurious blank line.

Comment: @egrep you are right, thanks. updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Note that the `@user` notifications don't work inside question and answer posts, only in comments and in the chat.

Comment: @Martin will try to remember next time